# Letter permutation MISSISISPPI, S come before any I

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

If there is no restriction, the number of ways to organize letter of MISSISSIPPI is,
$$ \frac{11!}{4!4!2!} $$

The restriction is,
all Ss come before any Is. So I group both letters, then there are total 4 letters. (PP,M, (Ss and Is)). 
$$ \frac{4!}{2!}$$.

Is it the correct way?

Comment: For restriction you neglected the case like MSSPSPSIIII or SSSMSPIIPII. Think how to accomodate them also.

Comment: Your idea of considering S and I the same letter is good, but it would yield (11!/8!2!1!) possibilities

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not.  The problem merely states that every $S$ appears before any $I$, not that the $S$s have to appear together or that the $I$s have to appear together.

There are eleven letters in $MISSISSIPPI$, so we have eleven positions to fill.  We can place the $M$ in eleven ways, which leaves ten open positions.  We choose two of them for the $P$s.  Once we have done that, there is only one way to fill the remaining positions with the $S$s and $I$s since every $S$ must appear before the first $I$.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{11}{1}\binom{10}{2}$$
admissible arrangements.

Comment: I think this is another approach. I ended up like this. First, group the Ss and Is and treat them as one letter. So there are $$ \binom{11}{8} $$ way to organize for Ss and Is. Then there is rest of letters (M, P, P) $$ \frac{3!}{2!} $$. Multiply these, $$ \binom{11}{8}  \frac{3!}{2!} $$.

Comment: Your count is correct.  However, you should say that you are choosing eight of the eleven positions for the $S$s and $I$s (since the eight letters do not form a block).  There is only way to place the $S$s and $I$s in those positions since every $S$ must appear before the first $I$.  We must choose one of the remaining three positions for the M.  The final two positions must be filled with the two $P$s.  We get $$\binom{11}{8}\binom{3}{1} = \binom{11}{8}\frac{3!}{1!2!} = \binom{11}{8}\frac{3!}{2!}$$  Our approaches are equivalent.  We just chose to fill the positions in different orders.

Comment: In my parenthetical remark in my previous comment, I meant to say that the eight letters may not form a block.

Answer (score 0):

Since all S should come before I consider the word SSSSIIII. Now we need to add the letters MPP. First letter we add can take 9 positikns (anywhere between letters or at ends of SSSSIIII). Second and third can be added at 10 and 11 positions. But P appears twice so we divide by 2!.  Final answer is (11!/8!)/2!